# Spring boot 2.1 test fails because of null property

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm not an expert in Spring Boot. I have to write tests for my `@RestController` methods but I have a problem, which is, the `@AutoWired` `ConfigurationProperties` class is `null` when the test class executes the `main controller`. I found many posts about a similar issue here but they really don't solve this problem. The strange thing is that in the @PostConstruct method of the `@RestController` the property class is not null, it is null only in the `@RequestMapping` methods I'm trying to test.

This is my `@SpringBootApplication` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties({MysqlProperties.class, CassandraProperties.class, GenericsProperties.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class REST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(REST.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the @RestController:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private MysqlProperties mysqlProperties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
       //Here mysqlProperties is not null and I can get elements from it
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/online", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String online(@RequestHeader(value = "email", required = true) String email, @RequestHeader(value = "password", required = true) String password) {
    Utils.logInfo(logger, "/online endpoint");

    //Here mysqlProperties is null
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + mysqlProperties.getAddress() + " WHERE email= ?";

    return new Return(Return.ERROR_MESSAGE, "Access denied, not superuser").toString();
}
```

This is the @ConfigurationProperties class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mysql")
public class MysqlProperties {

    String address;
    String database;
    ...

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    public void setDatabase(String database) {
        this.database = database;
    }
}
```

This is the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {REST.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({CassandraProperties.class, GenericsProperties.class, MysqlProperties.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MainControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private GenericsProperties genericsProperties;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        try {
            //mc.init();
            mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MainController()).build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger(MainControllerTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnline() throws Exception {
        //Return returnObject = new Return(Return.DONE_MESSAGE, "System online");
        Return returnObject = new Return(Return.ERROR_MESSAGE, "Access denied, not superuser");

        this.mvc.perform(get("/online")
                .header("email", genericsProperties.getSuperuser_email())
                .header("password", genericsProperties.getSuperuser_password()))
                //.contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json(returnObject.toString()));
    }
}
```

This is the package structure:

```
main
--java
----configurations
------MysqlProperties.java
----main
------MainController.java
----...
--resources
----application.properties
test
--java
----main
------MainControllerTest.java
```

The NullPointerException occurs in the MainController class at:

```
mysqlProperties.getAddress()
```

Any clue why it is not working? Thank you.

Comment: I do not see `getTable_systemusers()` present `mysqlProperties`. is it typo?

Comment: Yes sorry it is a typo, I edited it.

Comment: can you share application.properties my-sql parameters  because MysqlProperties  class initialized address and database variable from application.properties file and application.properties file inside test

Comment: @phcaze share your package structure

Comment: Ofcourse it is null as you are doing very hard to by pass all the test setup Sprng Boot has done. Remove your `@Before` method from your test (also `EnableConfigurationProperties`  don't have any value on a test class. Finally remove `@Configuration` from your `@ConfigurationProperties` class you will now get 2 instances instead of 2 (as well as the `@PropertySource` Spring Boot already handles that). The `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` are already implied through `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum, this solution works!

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired MysqlProperties mysqlProperties` is null bacause you created a new instance of `MainController` here:
`mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new MainController()).build();`
That instance will not be registered in the Spring context, therefore it will not be available for dependency injection.
You could read more about this issue [here](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/spring-mvc-java-autowired-component-null-repository-service/)

You should use an autowired `MainController` in your `MainControllerTest` class.

```
@Autowired
private MainController mainController;
```